# Regex for express router url to match path starting with /public/

Tags: regex, node.js, express, url-routing

**Requirement:** Need match all the urls starting with **/public/** token.

**What I have tried:** I tried the below regular expression to match all the paths which are starting with /public/

RegEx: `/\/public\/.*/`

When I use the same in regex101, it able to match the urls those are starting with /public/ token

But when tried the same in Express router tester (http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/?_ga=1.180272292.1056934125.1459765156) Its not working

Can any one help me know the reason why its not working!!

**Sample code:**

My expectation is that all the URLs stating with /public/ token should go via this route

```
router.route(/\/public\/.*/)
        .get(function(req, res, result){
            // TODO
        });
```

Exs:

```
https://localhost:8082/public/styles/styles.css
https://localhost:8082/public/js/rs.css
https://localhost:8082/public/images/qq.png
```

Comment: Some how the editor showing the incorrect reg-ex, it should be this one (/\/public\/.*/)

Comment: It seems that `.` and `*` are treated there as `\.` and `\*`.. see the code generated there in left bottom side

Comment: try this :- `\/public\/(.*)\/` or this `(.*)\/public\/(.*)\/`

Comment: *[Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/?_ga=1.253983752.1019678886.1459767961) is a handy tool for testing basic Express routes, although it does not support pattern matching.* ([source](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)). Just use the Express syntax `app.get(/\/public\/.*/, function(req, res) {
  res.send('/\/public\/.*/');
});`

Comment: Found one more fun thing [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html): *The `.` character can’t be used to capture a character in your capturing regexp.* Try `router.get('/\/public\/[[\\w\\W]]*', function);`

Comment: Do you even need to use Regex? Doesn't `router.route('/public/*')` match the requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and Ashley Thanks for you inputs, I able to fix the problem by following your inputs.

Comment: @KGopi: We posted the answers, consider upvoting/accepting to finalize the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [note](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html):

> [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/?_ga=1.253983752.1019678886.1459767961) is a handy tool for testing basic Express routes, although **it does not support pattern matching**.

Regex can be used with the following Express syntax:

```
app.get(/\/public\/.*/, function(req, res) { 
   res.send('/\/public\/.*/'); 
});
```

However, it seems you can use simpler wildcard pattern with `route.route`:

```
router.route('/public/*')
```

Where `*` matches any 0+ characters.

Answer (score 1):

Write-up from my comment:

While you can use Regex to match all URL's matching `'/public'`, you don't need to - you can just use the following for the route:

```
router.route('/public/*')
```